# Android is not selecting the Image to upload it on the Fire base

Tags: java, android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on a project that creates user profile on the fire base server but when i click on select button in the application it opens the gallery but not select image to get upload instead images are shown but unable to select to upload those images to fire base

```
ImageView imageView;
EditText Createname,CreateEmail;
StorageReference storageReference;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
public static final String STORAGE_PATH = "images/";
public static final String DATABASE_PATH = "mainObject";
private Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.insertImages);
    Createname= findViewById(R.id.insertname);
    CreateEmail = findViewById(R.id.insertEmail);
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(DATABASE_PATH);
}
public void browseImages(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("images/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Image"),0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==0 && requestCode == RESULT_OK){
     imageUri = data.getData();
     try {
         Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),imageUri);
         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
}
public String getActualImage(Uri uri){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));

}

public void uploadData(View view){
    if (imageUri != null){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
        progressDialog.show();
        StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(STORAGE_PATH+ System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+ imageUri);
        reference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                String NAME = Createname.getText().toString();
                String EMAIL = CreateEmail.getText().toString();
                Person person = new Person(NAME,EMAIL,taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                databaseReference.child(id).setValue(person);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double totalProgress= (100*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded %"+(int)totalProgress);

                    }
                });


    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Select Data First",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void viewAllData(View view){

}
```

}
[The Images that need to upload look like this, whitish touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ltKM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe you're missing somethings like below:

1. Give permission to access device's storage, see how to request permission at https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
2. Use Firebase Storage instead of update local photo URI into user's update request:

   - See how to setup Firebase Storage into Android project: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start?authuser=0
   - In default, only authenticated users can be manage files from Firebase Storage, if you need to handle it manually, you can change Firebase Storage Rules, follow this article to learn about rules in Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files?authuser=0
3. Please remember that you need to upload file into Firebase Storage. After uploaded successfully, you will got an URI. Use that URI as user's profile photo URI in UserUpdateRequest instance. This is exactly URI from server. Otherwise, URI is just local file from user's device, It will be not update when user changed their devices.